# Android: views in container still clickable after container view set to View.GONE

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I have a `LinearLayout` that is a view in a `FrameLayout`. This `LinearLayout` sits on top in the frame.

Within this `LinearLayout`, there are some `TextView`s that are clickable. When I set the `LinearLayout` to `View.GONE`, everything goes away as expected **except the TextViews are still clickable.**

Why is this? And how do I avoid it other than setting all the clickable `TextView`s to `View.GONE`?

**XML**

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/match_settings_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="#40c0a9"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:padding="10dp" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:baselineAligned="false" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <com.walintukai.lfdate.CustomFontTextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textColor="#fff"
                    android:text="@string/lbl_age" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <com.walintukai.lfdate.CustomFontBoldTextView
                    android:id="@+id/age_setting"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/white_rounded_bg"
                    android:padding="6dp"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textColor="#0099cb"
                    android:text="18 to 99" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:baselineAligned="false" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <com.walintukai.lfdate.CustomFontTextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textColor="#fff"
                    android:text="@string/lbl_location" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <com.walintukai.lfdate.CustomFontBoldTextView
                    android:id="@+id/location_setting"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/white_rounded_bg"
                    android:padding="6dp"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textColor="#0099cb"
                    android:text="Any Distance" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

**Activity**

```
// Handles expanding match settings window
    final ToggleButton btnShowMatchSettings = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_show_match_settings);
    btnShowMatchSettings.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        LinearLayout container = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.match_settings_container);

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {
                btnShowMatchSettings.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ico_menu_open);
                container.setAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(DashboardActivity.this, R.anim.slide_down));
                container.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                ageSetting = (CustomFontBoldTextView) findViewById(R.id.age_setting);
                ageSetting.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                ageSetting.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        new AgePickerDialog().show(getFragmentManager(), "agePicker");
                    }
                });

                locationSetting = (CustomFontBoldTextView) findViewById(R.id.location_setting);
                locationSetting.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                locationSetting.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        new LocationPickerDialog().show(getFragmentManager(), "locationPicker");
                    }
                });
            }
            else {
                btnShowMatchSettings.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ico_menu);
                container.setAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(DashboardActivity.this, R.anim.slide_up));
                container.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                ageSetting.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                locationSetting.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that you change the visibility of a view doesn't mean that they are destroyed. 
You should try adding something like this

yourButton.setClickable(false) ;